# How to avoid SupportMapFragment with setRetainInstance(true) leaking first Activity

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, memory-leaks

I'm developing app, which uses GoogleMaps. I'm using fragment oriented navigation pattern - there's one main Activity with fragments, acting like page screens. For simpler state handling those fragments are set to retain their instances by themselves (i.e. setRetainInstance is true, all fields, linked to views are set to null onDestroyView of fragment). One of those fragments contains GoogleMap in itself. For better performance on screen rotation, I use setRetainInstance(true) for SupportMapFragment. But each time first Activity, in which SupportMapFragment was created, is leaked. If I remove setRetainInstance(true) - there's no memory leak.

Code for onCreate in MainActivity:

```
@Override 
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    //if activity created from scratch
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        MyMapFragment fragment = mFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(fragmentTag);
        if (fragment == null) {
            fragment = MyMapFragment.newInstance();
        }
        if (fragment != null) {
            fragment.setRetainInstance(true);
            mFragmentManager
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, fragmentTag)
                    .addToBackStack(fragmentTag)
                    .commit();
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Code in MyMapFragment's

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getChildFragmentManager();
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(MAP_FRAGMENT_TAG);
    if (mapFragment == null) {
        mapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
        mapFragment.setRetainInstance(true);
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.map_container, mapFragment, MAP_FRAGMENT_TAG).commit();
    }
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    ...
}
```

Here's screenshots of memory leak:

[Leak Canary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0UNm.png)

[hprof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DjD2m.png)

Is there a way to avoid this memory leak without initializing MapFragment every time Activity is recreated?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Unfortunately, nope... I had to stick to the safe solution - I don't use setRetainInstance(true) on SupportMapFragment anymore. So now my maps are re-initializing each time device is rotated

Comment: Same. I'm using an LruCache for the bitmaps displayed on the map so they can be applied more quickly after rotation. There is still flicker and I'm seeing some OOM errors. Ironically leaking may have been more memory efficient. I would think a GoogleMap should be able to survive rotations.